# Automapper with dynamic values C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, automapper

I am a bit stuck, hoping for guidance.  I have 2 tables, Header and Details.  However, the details is a bit different than most, and allows for a way to dynamically store data.:  Yes, I am aware that I can create a table storing the details in the standard fashion, but the nature of the app needs to be more dynamic on the database side.  I also realize I will have to modify the DTOs for different incarnations of the app, but this model is what I need to accomplish.

```
public class Header
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string HeaderName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Detail> Details { get; set; }

}
public class Detail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HeaderId { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use the following DTOs:

```
public class DataForDisplayDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string HeaderName { get; set; }
    public string TaskToPerform { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
public class DataForCreationDto
{
    public string HeaderName { get; set; }
    public string TaskToPerform { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

The data would be stored in the details in this fashion:

```
{
    "FieldName": "tasktoperform",
    "FieldProperty": "Thing to Do"
},
{
    "FieldName": "location",
    "FieldProperty": "Over there"
}
```

I am trying to use the Automapper to make it so I can read and write to the database using the DTOs, but I think I may be trying something it can't do.

Is there an article or something that anyone knows about that can point me in the direction to go?  Or even the right keywords to search online for it.  Is it even possible?

I suppose if it is not possible, I will have to do things a bit more manually, which is the last option, I am just hoping to do this with Automapper.

Thanks!

Comment: Manual job is one-time job, which "just works" ;)

Comment: Definitely considering it :)

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: "needs to be more dynamic than that" meaning what? Can you give some examples? Is a column changing? It sounds like you expect to have different versions of the app with different schemas but want one way to map them?

Answer (score -1):

How about deriving your DTO from a base class that uses reflection to generate a mapping, and cache that mapping.

This way your DTO need only inherit a base class.

Comment: Thanks :)  I will consider that, too.  I was wondering if Automapper was even the right tool for the job.